# Python: Left-side bracket assignment

Tags: python, kotti

So I found this code inside [Kotti](https://github.com/Pylons/Kotti):

```
[child] = filter(lambda ch: ch.name == path[0], self._children)
```

And I was wondering: What do the left-hand square brackets do? I did some testing in a python shell, but I can't quite figure out the purpose of it.
Bonus question: What does the `lambda` return? I would guess a tuple of `(Boolean, self._children)`, but that's probably wrong...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is list unpacking, of a list with only a single element. An equivalent would be:

```
child = filter(lambda ch: ch.name == path[0], self._children)[0]
```

(The exception would be if more than one element of `self._children` satisfied the condition- in that case, Kotti's code would throw an error (too many values to unpack) while the above code would use the first in the list).

Also: `lambda ch: ch.name == path[0]` returns either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Aweseome answer! I never knew about this.

Comment: Ha! sorry, I could not accept it right away so I forgot it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

```
[child] = filter(lambda ch: ch.name == path[0], self._children)
```

This sets child to the first element of result. It is a syntaxic sugar for list[0] = ...[0]. It also can be two element, like `[a, b] = [10, 20]`, which is sugar for `a = 10; b = 20`

Also, the amount of elements from the right side should be the same for the left side, otherwise an exception will be thrown

Comment: `[a, b] = [10, 20]` is not sugar for `a, b = 10, 20` (Which is what I think you meant--`a = 10, b = 20` is not valid python.) It's roughly equivalent, but I wouldn't call it "sugar" as it doesn't make anything easier for the programmer. If anything, it makes the programmer type an additional 2 characters.

Comment: Use a semicolon then, as it is valid python and is synonymous with 2 lines of code: `a = 10; b = 20`.